# Pie chart is showing wrong value for key

Tags: jasper-reports, pie-chart

I am developing a program that create a report with data of diferents persons stored in a database.

The report is created fine, but the chart isn't correct. I'm trying to show the distribution of the professions.

This is my report:

[image]

As you can see, all the professions have the same count. It's wrong because Cantante and Profesor appear two times.

I define the chart in iReport of the following way:

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using ***net.sf.jasperreports.chart.pie.ignore.duplicated.key*** property but forgot to sort data at dataset.

If you are using groups at *JasperReports* you should always remember about data sorting.

Looks like all you need is to sort data by ***profession*** field.

### Example built with *Jaspersoft Studio 7.1.0*

#### Datasource

Using simple *csv datasource* is enough for example.

The content of my *professions.csv* file is very simple. The first row is going for fields names.

```
name,age,profession
Miguel,25,Professor
Toni,22,Engineer
Josefa,34,Singer
Andres,27,Mechanic
Jony,41,Professor
Lola,33,Singer
```

The name of *dataadapter* at *JSS* for my example will be *professions.csv*.

#### The report template, *jrxml* file

I used main dataset at pie chart for showing information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="NotSortedDataChart" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="09483b77-da8e-4dbb-a87d-ae46c27df140">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="professions.csv"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.pie.ignore.duplicated.key" value="true"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="age" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="profession" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <sortField name="profession"/>
    <group name="ProfessionGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{profession}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="15" uuid="edda065f-1a67-4f94-a2e9-1fc0042e4d32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="145" height="15" uuid="95bf7063-fe77-48d6-924a-e0028b8ec0c4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Age]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="245" y="0" width="125" height="15" uuid="97f91177-abd3-416d-abb1-e8692f96dc5c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Profession]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="15" uuid="b10df174-e36e-402d-ad52-4aa15dbebd49"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="125" height="15" uuid="5c66bca9-34af-49a6-a4fe-87c4e945f31b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="245" y="0" width="145" height="15" uuid="d169f529-349c-4c84-b697-680048eabd94"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{profession}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="240" splitType="Stretch">
            <pieChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="50" y="40" width="200" height="200" uuid="7454b149-6176-4070-8f9b-dd10bbd8f47a"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <pieDataset>
                    <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{profession}]]></keyExpression>
                    <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProfessionGroup_COUNT}]]></valueExpression>
                    <labelExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProfessionGroup_COUNT}.toString()]]></labelExpression>
                </pieDataset>
                <piePlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                </piePlot>
            </pieChart>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The key features of this example are:

- using ***[net.sf.jasperreports.chart.pie.ignore.duplicated.key](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.chart.pie.ignore.duplicated.key)*** property,
- using group by ***profession*** field
- and applying sorting by this (***profession***) field.

If **not all** values of ***profession*** field are **unique** you will get an error:

`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Key Professor is duplicated in pie dataset.`

The using ***[net.sf.jasperreports.chart.pie.ignore.duplicated.key](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.chart.pie.ignore.duplicated.key)*** property allow us to build report even with duplicated values calculated by *key* expression:

```
<keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{profession}]]></keyExpression>
<valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProfessionGroup_COUNT}]]></valueExpression>
<labelExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProfessionGroup_COUNT}.toString()]]></labelExpression>
```

Without sorting the data (just remove `<sortField name="profession"/>` row from *jrxml*) the result will be wrong, like at your screenshot:

[image: The result with wrong sorting]

After applying sorting, for example with help of code

```
<sortField name="profession"/>
```

we will get the right result:

[image: The right result after applying sorting]